# IEEE integer standard

Tags: floating-point, integer, standards, ieee

IEEE 754 defines floating point standards for computers. Is there such a similar standard for integers? Whenever I search for something like that, I end up at IEEE 754!

C/C++ defines `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` as default integral values while Java defines `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long` as default integral values. On the other end, Python only gives a single `int` as integral type. Some of these, despite having same names, stores different capacities of integers. Looking at this sequence, when/if 128-bit integers arrive, C/C++ may them `long long long`.

So, is there a standard (IEEE or any other) integral format which standardizes integers the way there is one for floats?

**EDIT**: @JohnColeman has some good points in comments. There are some operations on integers like remainder which are ambiguously defined. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#:%7E:text=a%20mod%20n.-,In%20programming%20languages,-%5Bedit%20source%5D) you can see different implementations of modulo operation in different languages. Similarly, there exists a lot of representations for negative numbers. Although 2's complement is popular, nowhere I've heard it is the standard. Even positive numbers have two variants ;) (normal binary and gray code).

Comment: Interesting question. The IEEE standard for floats constrains operations on them. If something like that exists for integers, I don't think that there would be so much variety in remainder operators and negative numbers.